# android home screen widget x-y coordinates

Tags: android, widget

Is it possible to obtain the X-Y coordinates of a home screen widget? I need to display a pop-up relative to the position of the widget, so I need to get the X and Y coordinates.

Thank you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's part of the Intent used when clicking a widget. Just call getSourceBounds() on the Intent used to launch your Activity.

Comment: Great ... I took me a while to figure out that this method is only available in framework 2.1 and later. 

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This codding also helped me to find out X-Y coordinates of a  widget on the home screen.

```
   ImageView iv; 
   iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(bb.this, "text", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    values    = new int[2]; 
                    view.getLocationOnScreen(values);
                    Log.d("X & Y",values[0]+" "+values[1]);
                }
            });
```